# Changing the IP Address in Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, ip, ping

I am trying to change the IP address in Solaris, but am failing to do so.

The IP address needs to be a fixed number, like 10.0.11.10

I have tried changing the IP address in `/etc/hosts` which I changed the hostname and the IP address, but when I try `ping` the computer name, it says:

```
Ping request could not find host SolarisTest. Please check the name and try again.
```

I have done what they told me to try on [this site](http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-change-an-ip-address-on-solaris.html). But still stuck.

They say to do this: "If using Solaris 9 or above, users may need to edit the IP address in `/etc/inet/ipnodes`" which I did, and the file looks exactly the same as the `/etc/hosts/` file. I already changed the IP address in the `/etc/hosts/` file.

- Please can someone show me how to **change the IP address on Solaris 11**?

**Edit**

I have tried `ifconfig -a` and it showed me the old IP address `10.0.10.80` and I changed `/etc/hosts/` to show `10.0.11.10` - so I have no idea why it is always changing.

**2nd Edit**

This [link](http://www.adminschoice.com/solaris-network-configuration) also shows stuff about how to change the IP address, as I have tried that as well, and also got nowhere.

Comment: If ifconfig still shows the old address, you didn't follow that article you link to. `/etc/hosts` is only for host name resolution (like DNS). It has no bearing on what IP addresses are affected to local interfaces.

Comment: @Mat Well I carried on doing more research into this, and saw this to try: `sudo #ifconfig hme0 10.0.11.10 netmask 255.0.0.0 up` and it still didn't work. In fact it showed this error: `ifconfig: could not create address: No such interface` - Does that mean that the interface is wrong? **What is the interface?**

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1458/fpcwh.html#scrolltoc - Solaris has extensive documentation, you should go ahead and browse the introductory parts. If you blindly type commands found on random blogs, you're likely to lock yourself out of your box at one point or another :-)

Comment: Thank you @Mat. I have given up trying, both myself and my colleague and I have tried. So he suggested I try from scratch and redo the installation ... at least from there I can configure it properly.

Comment: @Mat http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1458/gjwiq.html#gjgob#scrolltoc rather

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Solaris 11 network interfaces manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1458/gjwiq.html#gjgob#scrolltoc) in chapter 8 “Configuring an IP Interface”:

```
ipadm create-addr -T static -a 10.0.11.10/24 eth0/staticip
```

`eth0` is the name of the Ethernet interface (listed by `ipadm show-if`). `staticip` is a name that you can choose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have just tried this on the interface version (using Terminal) and I got this returned: `ipadm: cannot create address: Persistent operation on temporary object` - **What does that mean?**

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are on Solaris 11:

I believe the above answer is too simplistic.

I've got a feeling that your current IP address is obtained via DHCP and now you want to switch to a fixed address ?

First you need to disable Network Automagic. (it will get in your way if all you want is a static IP address). Do it like this:

```
netadm enable -p ncp DefaultFixed
```

Next step is that you must explicitly create an IP interface. (because you've disabled network automagic). Do it like this:

```
ipadm create-ip net0
```

Now go ahead and assign a static IP address on that IP interface:

```
ipadm create-addr -T static -a 10.0.11.10/24 net0/v4
```

That's it. No need to reboot.

I don't know what netmask you want to use so the "/24" (equivalent of mask 255.255.255.0) is a guess. The "v4" means that you want to create an IPv4 address as opposed to a IPv6 address.

Comment: Thank you for this, but it is all sorted now. I used the GUI to do it all. But it looks like this would've worked too!

Answer (score 1):

I know you already sorted it out a long time ago using the GUI but, for the record, the way to overcome from the command line the issue you experienced :

```
# ipadm create-addr -T static -a 192.168.1.100/24 net0/v4static
ipadm: cannot create address: Persistent operation on temporary object
```

is to turn interface persistence on by recreating it:

```
# ipadm show-if -o all net0
IFNAME     CLASS    STATE    ACTIVE CURRENT       PERSISTENT OVER
net0       ip       down     no     bm4---------  ----       --
# ipadm delete-ip net0
# ipadm create-ip net0
# ipadm create-addr -T static -a 192.168.1.100/24 net0/v4static
# ipadm show-if -o all net0
IFNAME     CLASS    STATE    ACTIVE CURRENT       PERSISTENT OVER
net0       ip       down     no     bm46--------  46--       --
# ifconfig net0
net0: flags=100001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 6
        inet 192.168.1.100 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 0:14:4f:12:34:56
```